# FontAwesome5 character present in font but not defined?

Tags: fontawesome, fontawesome5

Are all the icons in the free FontAwesome fonts meant to be defined by the `fontawesome5` package?

Best I can make out from the sources, the icon names are defined automatically in the package, but the icon I want ([right-from-bracket](https://fontawesome.com/icons/right-from-bracket?s=solid&f=classic)) returns an error if I try to use `\faRightFromBracket` or `\faIcon{right-from-bracket}`. It's not in the `fontawesome5` manual either.

This icon *is* definitely in the font in my TeX system though (which hasn't been manually adjusted or updated in any way). I can load the font directly and output the character.

I'm using LuaLaTeX, but the icon isn't defined with PDFLaTeX either.

What am I misunderstanding?

### MWE

```
% TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\fontawesomefreesolid}{FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf}
\begin{document}
\faIcon{right-from-bracket}

{\fontawesomefreesolid ^^^^f2f5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: perhaps it is a new glyph. Write Marcel a mail (see docu).

Comment: No idea if  `\faIcon{right-from-bracket}` should work or not in the free version, but in the link of the question appear `sign-out-alt` as alias, and   `\faIcon{sign-out-alt}` or `\faSignOut*` produce that icon (and this appear  in the CTAN manual).

Comment: @Fran oooh. That's a useful piece of information. I didn't see that or think to search under it in the manual. Thanks.

Comment: @Fran, I'll take that as an answer if you like. It's easier to search for icons on the website, and it does seem that in general the package uses those aliases for icon names rather than the main names on the website.

Comment: Ooo. I discover something else. If I search for version 5 on the website, it does use `sign-out-alt` as the main name. OK! My problem is fully solved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.